# Parsing of a Hex file to Output with different number of headers

Tags: c++, parsing, csv

I am writing a parser for a hex file to correspond to certain fields. Now in this i have different types with different headers. There are a few solutions that i can think of first of is store all of them and then display according to the headers. But i want to generate a template wchich can be used so that it can be reused.

Basically what i am doing is parsing a huge hex file and then decoding it to decimal format and then depending on the values placing it into the corresponding column.

The problem i am facing is i did not think of it before hand and have completed the parsing but now the output format needs to have just one column with all the headers. and rows should have corresponding data. Padding is a solution but it is very tedious. Any STL solution would work i think.

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Despite a reasonably long description, it's not clear what you are trying to do.  When you say 'hex' file, you just mean an ordinary file with binary data?  Are you trying to output this data as it would look in a hex editor?  In that case, I assume the 'headers' are the row headers with the file offset.  Otherwise, it would seem you are trying to process some kind of file format that you have not adequately described.  Can you give more information?

Comment: Ok 1. I have a hex file, for example 00-monday 01-tuesday,wednesday,thursday so 00 has one column and 01 has 3 columns each byte value has a significance. 2. So what i am trying to do is everytime i find a 00 it has to go to the column monday and 01's values should be placed in the remaining 3 columns. 3. The headers need to be displayed once and the value corresponding to them should be placed in rows vertically downwards everytime it is found.

Comment: Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You'd better edit your question and post a sample file and sample output, or put up a link to a file that can be downloaded.  If your existing code is reasonably compact, you could post that too.  It would help a lot.  Normally I'm able to read between the lines and work out what people are trying to say, but in this case I'm struggling.